# Cron not able to find correct versions of ruby and bundler gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, ruby

I have cron running for rails application on EC2 instance, but it fails with error -

```
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
```

if I run bundle command with ubuntu user or sudo user that works.
I have added cron using crontab -e command.

Some Troubleshooting I did (displays same result with sudo as well) -

```
> which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby

> which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

But if add these command as which ruby and which bundle in crontab and output it over logs, it shows -

Cron has -

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'which ruby >> /home/ubuntu/logs/cron.log 2>&1'
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'which bundle >> /home/ubuntu/logs/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Output -

```
/usr/bin/ruby
/bin/bash: bundle: command not found
```

so basically my cron is taking wrong ruby from system, what should I do to correct that ?
I want to take ruby from my /usr/local/bin/ruby and then it can find bundle as well.

Thanks !!

Comment: This isn't really a crontab problem, more a $PATH problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the full path, as thince notes.

You should also be able to set the PATH at the top of your crontab:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
* * * * * ruby /home/ubuntu/scripts/ruby.rb >> /home/ubuntu/logs/cron.log 2>&1'
* * * * * bundle exec unicorn >> /home/ubuntu/logs/cron.log 2>&1'
```

Actually, I see that you have ruby installed in /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin.  In that case, if you want a specific ruby, fully specify the path.  With the cron as written above, because of the PATH order, you will execute /usr/bin/ruby and not /usr/local/bin/ruby.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cjc, I added this - 
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
it worked smoothly. Thanks !!